# get the image url from firebase storage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the image url from firebase storage  in flutter when I print in the **getImage()** it 
prints it correctly but when I call it in Hompage class it doesn't show any result 
**This is the code of helper class**
[https://gist.github.com/AbdouElnemr/69ce2b492ca42f07e483af70444d19ec](https://gist.github.com/AbdouElnemr/07453bc4ef193b8ed6d841d8bf2d5988)
this is the code for homepage class
https://gist.github.com/AbdouElnemr/07453bc4ef193b8ed6d841d8bf2d5988

Comment: You should post your code here and not link to it.

Answer (score 0):

What if your `getImage()` returns a `String` instead of `Future<String>`? I think you're trying to show the image before there is a downloadUrl. `Image.network()` constructor expects a `String` and not a `Future<String>`.